# PopupWindow can't show in onClick() of InnerClass

Tags: android, popupwindow

guys. I have a problem about PopupWindow in Android.
I have 2 Buttons, click either one will show a popupWindow which is a member variable in the outer class.
    The content and layout of either popupWindow is different.
    I update content of popipWindow in onClick method like this:

```
    bt1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener{       
        onClick(View v){
            mPopupWin.setContentView(R.layout.layout_a);
    });

    bt2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener{       
        onClick(View v){
            mPopupWin.setContentView(R.layout.layout_b);
    });
```

When I click either of them at first time, it works, popupWindow show, but when I click the other one, popupWindow doesn't show expectably(the mPopupWin has been dismissed correctly before, and the contentView is not NULL, and the width/height are not 0, I checked...).
When I click the second button again, the popupWindow show normally.
Then I try to use AsycnTask to setContentView() in doInBackground, and show popupWindow in onPostExecute(), everything works fine.

I can achieve my purpose by this way, butI still want to know what's the problem with the first way.
Hope your help, Thank U :)

Comment: Have you tried adding `mPopupWin.update();` after setting the `layout`?

Comment: Yes, I have done this. Still can't show the popupWindow

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had a chance to test it but try changing your code to use `update()`

```
 bt1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener{       
    onClick(View v){
        mPopupWin.setContentView(R.layout.layout_a);
       mPopupWin.update();
});

bt2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener{       
    onClick(View v){
        mPopupWin.setContentView(R.layout.layout_b);
        mPopupWin.update();
});
```

[According to the Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#setContentView%28android.view.View%29)

> This method has no effect if called when the popup is showing.

You may need to see if it [isShowing()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#isShowing%28%29) when deciding to call `update()` or not